# User defined background color using PHP

Tags: php, css, html-table, background-color

I'm trying to figure out how to change the background color of a table using PHP. I know I have value's wrong somewhere but I can't figure out where. I think I'm in the ballpark of getting this right I'm just missing something some where. Any help will be appreciated.

Background color:

```
    <form action= "post3.php" method="post">
    Author * : <input type="text" name="author"><br/>
    Email : <input type="text" name="email"><br/>
    Title * : <input type="text" name="title"><br/>

    Background color:
     <Input type = 'Radio' Name ='bgcolor' value= 'blue'
         <?PHP print $blue_status; ?>
         >Blue
     <Input type = 'Radio' Name ='bgcolor' value= 'red'
         <?PHP print $red_status; ?>
         >Red
    <P>

    Tag:
    <input type="checkbox" name="tag[]" value="General Interests"> General Interests
    <input type="checkbox" name="tag[]" value="Local Schools"> Local Schools
    <input type="checkbox" name="tag[]" value="Safety"> Safety
    <br/>

    <select name="City" id="City">
        <option value="0" selected="selected">Select any City</option>
        <option value="Arlington">Arlington</option>
        <option value="Dallas">Dallas</option>
        <option value="Ft. Worth">Fort Worth</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    Comment * : <br/><textarea name="comment" rows="5" cols="40"></textarea><br>
    <input type="Submit" name="SubmitThis" value="Preview">
  </form>
```

PHP:

```
$blue_status = 'unchecked';
    $red_status = 'unchecked';

    if (isset($_POST['SubmitThis'])) {

        $selected_radio = $_POST['bgcolor'];

        if ($selected_radio == 'blue') {

            $blue_status = 'bluebg';

        }
        else if ($selected_radio == 'red') {

            $red_status = 'redbg';

        }

    }
```

The table:

```
  $output = "<table border=\"1\" style=\"width:30%\">
  <tr>
    <td>Author:</td>
    <td>$author</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Title:</td>
    <td>$title</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Tag:</td>
    <td>$tagStr</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>City:</td>
    <td>$cities</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Comment:</td>
    <td>$comment</td>
  </tr>

  </table>
";
```

CSS:

```
.redbg{
    background-color: indianred;
}
.bluebg{
    background-color: lightblue;
}
```

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything. Plus, it makes it that much more harder to diagnose it without knowing what your HTML form looks like; missing parts.

Comment: your missing `class=your_class`

Comment: @Dagon they "skipped" it.... class.

Comment: @Fred-ii- your jokes lack any class

Comment: @Dagon *ah gee, thanks!* ;-) ditto

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'm a classy dude :-)

Comment: @Dagon that ye are matey

Comment: i'm glad he wasn't using `id` its harder to pun

Comment: Hm... we'll eventually come up with something.

Comment: Haha thanks for the reply guys, so for instance I put class=$selected_radio in the table field?

Comment: im confused about the radio button to table relationship

Comment: [comment #1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29551522/user-defined-background-color-using-php#comment47254483_29551522) hasn't been answered, so I can't give a solution. You have a stab at it @Dagon

Comment: add class to table? or is it table rows?

Comment: Sorry about that, I should have been more descriptive.  I need to change the background color of the table depending on what they select between blue and red in the radio fields.

I'm adding in the php snippet you said to right now will post what it relays.

Comment: Edited the code to include the entire form. Let me know if theres anything else you guys need to solve this. The error report snipet doesnt report anything back.